# Validate f:viewParam value to be one of a select set of allowable values

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2, viewparams

I am learning JSF 2.2 and I am having a little trouble finding a good answer that i can understand as to how to have more for validation on a GET parameter.

I have a source.xhtml file that has a link it like this:

```
<h:link value="ALTER" outcome="/main/showSqlTemplates.xhtml">
    <f:param name="type" value="ALTER" />
</h:link>
```

and in my destination.xhtml i have code that looks like this:

```
<f:metadata>
<f:viewParam id="type" name="type" value="#{showSqlTemplateManagedBean.type}" required="true" requiredMessage="Invalid page access. Please use a link from the menu."/>                    
</f:metadata>
<h:message for="type" class="bold"></h:message>
<br/>TYPE is : #{showSqlTemplateManagedBean.type}
```

and my bean class looks like this:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class ShowSqlTemplateManagedBean {

    String type = "";

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public ShowSqlTemplateManagedBean() {

    }
}
```

as you can see i have used the "required" attribute to make sure the type parameter is at least there and everything is working fine as far as that goes. But i would like to do more validation.

Specifically I want to make sure the value of the String type will only be ALTER,INSERT,UPDATE OR DELETE.

Is this where a custom validator comes in? A custom validator seems to be over kill for such a simple validation check. I am sure I am missing something. Perhaps put something in the PostConstruct init() method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make it an `enum`.

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class ShowSqlTemplateManagedBean {

    public enum Type {
        ALTER, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE;
    }   

    private Type type;

    public Type getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(Type type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

}
```

JSF has a builtin converter for enumns which will kick in fully transparently. Any invalid value will cause a conversion error which you can customize via `converterMessage` attribute of the `<f:viewParam>`.

Enums have more benefits elsewhere in the code, too.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, explicitly initializing properties with an empty string (or even `null`) is poor practice. Don't do that anymore. Moreover, initializing managed bean properties with a non-empty-string or non-null should happen in a `@PostConstruct` annotated method.